VSCode unwantedly inserts and modifies PHP source code (autocomplete?)
In my environment, VSCODE runs on MacOS, but editing is primarily done via SSH on remote systems.  I moved to the latest version of MacOS (Sequoia 15.0) this week and (among other things) this required me to update (read: reinstall) my vscode implementation.  That has not been without its pains.
One primary pain source is that (apparently) PHP Intellphense (or other) makes code suggestions (sometimes very off-the-wall suggestions), seemingly randomly, and if I so much as press the space bar, the 'suggested' code is inserted.  I have not yet been able to determine the source of this.  I hope someone might recognize the effect, and I might be led in the right direction here on SO to turn that function off.  in the following example, I simply typed } else { and pressed ENTER.  I have no idea how it came up with code suggestion that appeared in the else block... but if I pressed space bar, it would be inserted.  I am a fast typist and this happens more often than you might think.

A secondary nuisance is that the PHP function parameter names are inserted within the code (visual only, not stored).  Not just some select parameters, but all of them. So what I am looking at is not the actual code.  Maybe useful for some, but I want to see (only) what the code actually looks like, especially on lines I'm not actively changing.  This messes up with alignment and a number of other cosmetic aspects of the code, and I'd like to turn it off.  Here is an example of that.  The words 'key: ' and 'array: ' are NOT in my code here.

Note: If you need a list of extensions or whatnot, please suggest what you need; I will be happy to provide.

I found the answet to this in the settings.  Or at least the answer to most of it.  (On occasion, it still shows phantom code that space-bar will insert, but it's so much better now.)
These following settings, I modified to address the questions above, and it seems to be working as I like:
PHP › Inlay Hints › Parameters: By Reference (unchecked)
PHP › Inlay Hints › Parameters: Enabled (unchecked)
PHP › Inlay Hints › Types: Lambda Parameter (unchecked)
PHP › Inlay Hints › Types: Return (Disable)
PHP › Inlay Hints › Types: Suppress Variable From Literal (unchecked)

